# How to get rid of the coolant fan noise in NVR

Tags: fan, cooling

Hi I'm using the following NVR

https://www.dahuasecurity.com/products/All-Products/Network-Recorders/Lite-Series/NVR4/L-Series/1HDD/NVR4108HS-4KS2/L

But the fan is really noisy enough to disturb the sleep.

Please checkout the [AV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13W2MsRnve7HH_5ln23VZdWsBpJIzNYwk/view?usp=sharing)

What I did so far.

I opened the NVR and tried adjusting the cooling fan but the noise started coming again.

I can't remove the fan as this would reduce the lifespan of circuits.

Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Professional or pro-sumer level computer equipment is designed with reliability in mind, not comfort. The expectation for these products is usually that they will be in a room away from people. The fans for these types of equipment are loud because their purpose is to move lots of air. Their purpose is not to be quiet. You could try to identify the specific fan model inside this unit and see if there are compatible fans that provide sufficient cooling but have a lower noise level, or you could put the unit in a location where noise is not a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professional or pro-sumer level computer equipment is usually designed more with reliability in mind than comfort. The expectation for these products is that they will be in a room away from people. The fans for these types of equipment are loud because their purpose is to move lots of air. Their purpose is not to be quiet.

You probably have just two possibly solutions:

1. Try to identify the specific fan model inside this unit and see if there are compatible fans that provide sufficient cooling but produce less noise
2. Put the unit in a location where there is ample ventilation and noise is not a factor.